# Xamarin IOS Cant Bind function or callback In JavascriptCore

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, javascriptcore

Following the example here: [JSContext](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.JavaScriptCore.JSContext/#Calling_C_code_from_JavaScript)

I receive the following exception:

```
{TypeError: myCSharpObject.myFunc is not a function. (In 'myCSharpObject.myFunc()', 'myCSharpObject.myFunc' is undefined)}
```

My code is as follows:

```
        JSContext _context;
        _context = new JSContext();

        var jsCallback = new MyJSExporter();

        _context[(NSString)"myCSharpObject"] = JSValue.From(jsCallback, _context);

        var result = _context.EvaluateScript("myCSharpObject.myFunc();");
```

With the protocol defined as:

```
[Protocol]
    interface IMyJSVisibleProtocol : IJSExport
    {
        [Export("myFunc")]
        int MyFunc();

        [Export("Arity2:With:")]
        NSObject Arity2With(NSObject arg1, NSObject arg2);
    }

    class MyJSExporter : NSObject, IMyJSVisibleProtocol
    {
        public int MyFunc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called!");
            return 42;
        }

        public NSObject Arity2With(NSObject arg1, NSObject arg2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Arity 2 function called with " + arg1 + " " + arg2);
            return (NSNumber)42;
        }
    }
```

And the exception handler as:

```
       _context.ExceptionHandler = (context, exception) => {
            // {TypeError: myCSharpObject.myFunc is not a function. (In 'myCSharpObject.myFunc()', 'myCSharpObject.myFunc' is undefined)}
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally fixed this for me was adding the build mtouch argument:

'--registrar:static'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong JSContext. 
In your code you are initialising new JSContext. Instead you want to get the JSContext from the document what you have loaded in webView : `var context = (JSContext)webView.ValueForKeyPath((NSString)"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext");`

[Here is fully working test view controller!](https://gist.github.com/halfred888/09ac0ac4706c90b55ab7bd8a20abb2fb)

Comment: I'm not using a webview intentionally, I want to run javascript behind a native view.

Comment: Please specify that in your question at first place. 

If you don't want to use webView, than you need to instantiate JSVirtualMachine and pass it as argument to JSContext. 
`JSVirtualMachine vm = new JSVirtualMachine();
 
var context = new JSContext(vm);`

Comment: Hi, I think your post is helpful. What actually fixed this for me was setting the build argument '--registrar:static'